# Step in Wikipedia's proof of the Gauss-Lucas Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, proof-explanation

I'm stuck trying to understand a step in [Wikipedia's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem#Proof) of the Gauss-Lucas Theorem:

> For any root $z$ of $P'$, if it is also a root of $P$, then the theorem is trivially true. Otherwise, we have for the logarithmic derivative
> $$0 = \frac{P'(z)}{P(z)} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{z-a_i}.$$

I do not understand the second equality. All I can see is that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{z-a_i} = \alpha\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{i\ne j}(z-a_j)}{P(z)}$$

Comment: Hint: You managed to write $P'(z)$ with the monomials $z - a_j$, can you do the same with $P(z)$?

Comment: Can you see that $\frac{\prod_{i\ne j}(z-a_j)}{P(z)} = \frac{1}{z-a_i}$?

Comment: Alternatively, since $\frac{P'}{P}$ is the logarithmic derivative, try to compute $(\ln P)'$.

Comment: @MartinR yes. What I meant in the post is that _that_ is _all_ I can see.

Comment: Ok so the mumerator is precisely $P’(z)$ by the product rule. Try this for small $n$ to convince yourself.

Comment: @peek-a-boo that's it! Thank you. Feel free to add that as an answer.